# How do display .avif images in not supporting browsers?

Tags: html, image, png, browser-support, avif

i want to all my big .png files to .avif . But Browsers like MS Edge etc. do not support .avif images. Is there any way to display .avif files in f.e. Edge, or provide the Browser two images (.png and .avif) and the browser decides, which image to display?

My Code:

`<a href="./"><img src="img/logo.avif" alt="Logo – Test"></a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to display .avif file in MS Edge, but there is a way for the browser to decide which format to display.

```
<a href="./">
  <picture>
    <source srcset="img/logo.avif" type="image/avif">
    <source srcset="img/logo.png" type="image/png">
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo – Test">
  </picture>
</a>
```

Comment: There is a way to play not supported video and audio formats like av1 in edge and safari or ogg in safari using software decoding in browser with ogv.js but not sure if such thing exists for images yet or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since January 2024 Edge (and all major browsers) support AVIF files